# How to calculate as quick as possible the base 3 value of an integer which is given as a huge sequence of decimal digits (more than one million)?

Tags: python, performance, radix

We got this task from our professor. Prerequisites are:

- Use Python 3 and use only build-in functions (no numpy).
- Main task: Find and store the result within 5 sec.
- Minor task, just nice to have: Find not only the value for base b=3, but also for the bases b=3**k (with k = 2,3,4).

Compared to our 1st straight-forward solution, we achieved an improvement by factor 96 (almost 100 times faster), but still it doesn't fulfill the 5 sec limit (currently, we are at 25 sec on an i7 laptop). [Our prof also has no solution in pure Python, so it's a bit of a research task.]

The complete code (including test calls) is here: Overall, it shows an improvement from originally 2400 sec (= 40 min) to 25 sec.  However, we need another performance improvement of factor 5.  Does someone have ideas and can help?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Convert a long random sequence of base-10 digits to integers base 3**k with k=1,2,3,4
# 
# Task for phdgroupA: length of sequence is 1.5*(10**6)
#                     time < 5 sec
#                     Use Python 3 (standard libraries only, no numpy) !
#
# Testcase with a very small sequence, made purely of the digit 7:
# (see sagemath or www.math.com/tables/general/base_conv.htm)
# numlen = 12  -->  777777777777_base10
#                =  2202100120200002212221010_base3
#                =  2670520085833_base9
#                =  2k9fi2np3_base27   ("digits": 0123456789ab...pq)
#                   [2, 20, 9, 15, 18, 2, 23, 25, 3]
#                =  2[61]5[18]8[53][30]_base81
#                   [2, 61, 5, 18, 8, 53, 30]
# 


# Convert decimal number n to a sequence of list elements with integer values in the range 0 to base-1.
# With divmod, it's ca. 1/3 faster than using n%b and then n//=b.
def numberToBase(n, b):
    digits = []
    while n:
        n, rem = divmod(n, b)
        digits.append(rem)
    return digits[::-1]


# Step 0: Create string of nlen digits
def step0(nlen):
    rd = 7  # which digit to repeat
    string_val = "".join(str(rd) for i in range(nlen))
    return string_val  # end of step0()


# Step 1: Convert string to int (the string contains only decimal digits)
def step1(string_val, option_chunk=True):
    if option_chunk == True:
        string_val_len = len(string_val)
        Chunk_len = 90000
        Read_len = 0
        int_valChunk = 0
        int_valLocal = 0
        ii = 0
        while Read_len < string_val_len:
            string_val_ChunkRead = string_val[ii*Chunk_len:(ii+1)*Chunk_len]
            Chunk_lenRead = len(string_val_ChunkRead)
            int_valChunk = int(string_val_ChunkRead)
            ii += 1
            int_valLocal = int_valLocal * 10**Chunk_lenRead + int_valChunk
            Read_len += Chunk_lenRead
        int_val = int_valLocal
    else:
        int_val = int(string_val)
    return int_val  # end of step1()


# Step 2: Convert given integer to another base
def step2(n, b, convsteps):
    nList = []
    if convsteps == 3:  # Here the conversion is done in 3 steps
        expos = 10000, 300
        base_a = b ** expos[0]
        base_b = b ** expos[1]
        nList1 = numberToBase(n, base_a)  # That's the time killer in this part
        nList2 = [numberToBase(ll, base_b) for ll in nList1]
        nList3 = [numberToBase(mm, b) for ll in nList2 for mm in ll]
        nList = [mm for ll in nList3 for mm in ll]
    else: # Do conversion in one bulk
        nList = numberToBase(n, b)
    return nList  # end of step2()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Calculate the string of digits
    numlen = 1500000  # number of digits = length of sequence
    string_value = step0(numlen)

    # Calculate the integer value of the string_value
    int_value = step1(string_value, option_chunk=True)

    # Convert int_value to list of numbers of the given bases
    convsteps = 3  # value of '3' makes step2() 50-60 times faster than value '1'

    b = 3
    numList = step2(int_value, b, convsteps)
    print('3**1: numList begin:', numList[:10])  # Expect: [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1]
```

Ideas may be, the chunk in step 1 could have another size? Or the two big bases for the intermediate conversions could be better balanced? Or the conversion from a string of decimal digits to a list of base 3 could be made more directly?

**Description**: The algorithm in the Python code above works in 3 steps:

- step 0: Get data.
    Here we create -- for test purposes -- a sequence of
    decimal digits of a length of 1.5 million digits.
    This value is normally a value we will get as a random value from file.
    The sequence is then stored as a string.
- step 1: Convert that string to an integer (default is base 10).
- step 2: Convert that integer to an integer of base b=3.

These three changes caused the most **improvements** (compared to the initial straight-forward solution):

1. The helper function *numberToBase*(n, b) which is used in step 2,
   converts the integer n to an integer of base b. The result is a list
   of decimal integers each of base b. Reading the list as a sequence
   is the resulting number in base b. The improvement was achieved by
   using the build-in function 'divmod' instead of the two commands n%b
   and n//=b within the while loop. This brought a performance boost of
   factor 2.
2. Function *step2*(n, b, convsteps) converts the given integer n into an
   integer of base b (with b=3). Initially, we called the
   helper function *numberToBase*(n, b) once. Then, we introduced
   intermediate steps in *step2*() -- so n wasn't migrated to the final
   base in one step, but in 3 steps. The intermediate bases are much
   bigger than the final basis b. These intermediate base conversions made step
   2 much quicker: 60 times.
3. Function *step1*() was made 4 times faster by reading the string in chunks and by doing the conversion for each junk separately.

Any idea is welcome. Please test your ideas with time() to also give a quantitative statement about its advantage. Other answers we checked here, didn't not use such a long sequence of decimal digits (in the string) or didn't focus on the performance of the base conversion.

Comment: On first blush, it looks to me like you are doing a lot of list slicing, which is expensive. consider using `memoryview` objects.

Comment: I wonder if you couldn't be processing the chunks in parallel, using the `multiprocess` library.  Normally Python is single threaded, this potentially could get you an 8x speed boost, or ~3s total time.  I did something like this a while back, starting with this approach as a reference: https://www.blopig.com/blog/2016/08/processing-large-files-using-python/  The same idea could be applied.

Comment: `int("1212012",3)` might (probably is) be faster than your base converion function

Comment: Consider using a base conversion algorithm with a better algorithmic complexity, such as what [GMP does](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html#Binary-to-Radix).

Comment: @Matt Morgan: Thanks for the link to this library, but we are not allowed to import other libraries and have to stay with pure Python. However, for curiosity we'll try this too.

Comment: he is saying to study their divide and conquer implementation ... not to use the GMP library

Comment: @phdgroupA The `multiprocess` module is part of the core Python library.  So, unless you're not allowed to `import` _anything_, it seems like that would be fair game.  But, I'm sure you know the rules of your game :)

Comment: The simplest optimization you're missing is that you're completely redoing the base conversion for bases `3`, `3**2`, `3**3`, and `3**4`. You don't need to do that. The base 3 representation can be used to compute the other representations much more quickly than if you had to start from a base 10 or Python `int` representation.

Comment: I'm not sure where the efficiency break-even point is for something like implementing your own Toom or FFT or NFT multiplication. It seems like the sizes you're working with might be able to benefit.

Comment: @phdgroupA: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I didn't say anything about `int(string, base)`.

Comment: @ user2357112: You are completely right, that the tests redo the base conversion for bases 3, 3**2, 3**3, and 3**4.  We are aware of that: We need to fulfill the time limit of 5 sec for the conversion to base 3 (the remaining bases with powers of could be done then much quicker).

Comment: @ user2357112: You wrote, I didn't say anything about int(string, base). You are completely right. Sorry for that.   Our second comment to you hat the right recipient. The first comment was meant to go to @Joran Beasley.

Comment: @Joran Beasley: Thanks for the hint, using int(string, base). We tried this. It was about factor 4 slower than our approach. If we might be wrong, please try it and tell us your code.

Answer (score 0):

ok I think this is the solution

```
base3to9={
   "00":"0",
   "01":"1",
   "02":"2",
   "10":"3",
   "11":"4",
   "12":"5",
   "20":"6",
   "21":"7",
   "22":"8",   
}
def convert_base3_to_base9(s):
    s = '0'*(len(s)%2) + s # ensure that the string is the right length
    return "".join(base3to9[s[i:i+2]] for i in range(0,len(s),2))

print(convert_base3_to_base9("12012120121010"))
# 5176533
```

then you can extrapolate it out

```
base3to27 = {
    "000":"0",
    "001":"1",
    ...
    "222":"Q"
}
def convert_base3_to_base27(s):
    s = '0'*(len(s)%3) + s # ensure that the string is the right length
    return "".join(base3to27[s[i:i+3]] for i in range(0,len(s),3))
```

basically no math to do at all ... just O(1) dict lookups ... should be really quite fast

Comment: I don't think you're handling the alignment right for non-multiple-of-2 or non-multiple-of-3 string lengths.

Comment: you might be right... i was just trying to give him another path to explore... the zfill is slow anyway ... i think i need to zfill the initial string not on every slice

Comment: @Joran Beasley: Thank for the suggestion to get the base 9, base 27 and base 81 integers -- after base 3 is calculated. -- However, the main time consuming task is to find this first integer with base 3. To do this quickly for such huge sequences of decimal digits gave us the problem.